# Material Components: Keeping Menu "Open" when clicking inside

Tags: javascript, jquery, material-design, addeventlistener, material-components

## MATERIAL COMPONENTS FOR THE WEB (MENUS)

---

**This question is in relation to the [Menu Component](https://material.io/components/web/catalog/menus/)**:

I've modified the code so that the menu opens when hovered instead of clicked. I'm now trying to make the menu stay open or closed when certain elements **inside** the menu are clicked on..But I'm having trouble getting it to work.

Can anyone help?

---

**Codepen Link:**
https://codepen.io/oneezy/pen/prejpw

---

**Example:**

- When `<li class="wont-close">` is clicked, the menu won't close. `menu.show();`
- When  `<li class="will-close">` is clicked, the menu will close. `menu.hide();`

[image]

#### *Here's my attempts:*

**HTML**

```
<section class="demo">
<div class="mdc-tab-bar">

    <!-- Hover Toggle (Wrapper) -->
    <div class="mdc-tab-wrapper hover-toggle">
        
        <!-- Button (For Looks) -->
        <a class="mdc-button mdc-button--raised mdc-button--primary mdc-tab mdc-ripple-upgraded" role="tab">
            Hover Menu
        </a>

        <!-- Hover Menu (Toggles Show/Hide)-->
        <nav class="mdc-simple-menu mdc-tab-items-wrapper" tabindex="-1">
            <ul class="mdc-simple-menu__items mdc-list" role="menu" aria-hidden="true">
                
                <!-- Won't Close (When Clicked) -->
                <li class="mdc-list-item wont-close clone-me" role="menuitem" tabindex="0">
                    <a class="category-items flex-horizontal between-stretch" href="#">
                        <i class="material-icons margin-r-5">keyboard_arrow_right</i>
                        <span>Won't Close</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                
                <!-- Will Close (When Clicked) -->
                <li class="mdc-list-item will-close" role="menuitem" tabindex="0">
                    <a class="category-items flex-horizontal between-stretch" href="#">
                        <i class="material-icons margin-r-5">close</i>
                        <span>Will Close</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                
            </ul>
        </nav>
        
    </div>
    
</div>
```

**JS**

```
    /* Hover Tabs
    *********************************/
    function hoverTabs() {
        var menuEls     =   document.querySelectorAll('.mdc-simple-menu');

        menuEls.forEach((el, i) => {
            var menu        =   new mdc.menu.MDCSimpleMenu(el);
            var toggle      =   $(el).closest('.hover-toggle')[0];
            var wontClose   =   $(el).closest('.wont-close'); // Not working...
            var willClose   =   $(el).closest('.will-close'); // Not working...

            toggle.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
                menu.show();
            });

            toggle.addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
                menu.hide();
            });


            /* Attempt #1 (Not working...)
            *******************************************************/
            // wontClose.addEventListener('click', function() {
            //  menu.show();
            // });

            // willClose.addEventListener('click', function() {
            //  menu.hide();
            // });


            /* Attempt #2 (Not working...)
            *******************************************************/
            // $('.wont-close').on('click', function(e) {
            //  e.preventDefault();
            //  menu.show();
            // });
            // 
            // $('.will-close').on('click', function(e) {
            //  e.preventDefault();
            //  menu.hide();
            // });

        });
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        hoverTabs();
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

When in doubt, create a pure CSS solution...

> I'm not accepting my answer as ***THE ANSWER*** because this is a hack.
>
> I just want to include this here to show my quick fix that does the exact same thing (right on down to the `cubic-bezier` animation).
>
> **NOTE:** I'm still using the *Material Design Styles* it ships with... Just not any of the JS.

**Codepen:** https://codepen.io/oneezy/pen/PKpJXV

---

**HTML**

```
    <!-- Hover Toggle (Wrapper) -->
    <div class="mdc-tab-wrapper hover-toggle clone-menu">

        <!-- Button (For Looks) -->
        <a class="mdc-button mdc-button--raised mdc-button--primary">Hover Menu</a>

        <!-- Hover Menu (Toggles Show/Hide)-->
        <nav class="mdc-simple-menu mdc-simple-menu--open" tabindex="-1">
            <ul class="mdc-simple-menu__items mdc-list" role="menu" aria-hidden="true">

                <!-- Won't Close (When Clicked) -->
                <li class="mdc-list-item clone-me" role="menuitem" tabindex="0">
                    <a class="category-items flex-horizontal between-stretch" href="#">
                        <i class="material-icons margin-r-5">keyboard_arrow_right</i>
                        <span>Menu Item</span>
                    </a>
                </li>

            </ul>
        </nav>

    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
/* Reset
========================================================================= */
* { box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0; padding: 0; text-decoration: none; }

html,
body,
main                { display: flex; flex-direction: column; height: 100%; }

section             { padding: 5%; }
a                   { color: var(--mdc-theme-primary); }
h1              { background: black; color: white; padding: .25rem 1rem; position: relative; }
h1 span             { font-weight: normal; font-size: 16px; position: absolute; right: 24px; top: 14px; display: inline-block; text-transform: uppercase; }


/* Material Design Menu
========================================================================= */
/* Menu Styles */
.wrapper                                                 { position: relative; display: flex; justify-content: space-between; }
.wrapper .hover-toggle                               { display: inline-block; position: relative; }
.wrapper .hover-toggle .mdc-button               { z-index: 2; position: relative; color: white; min-width: auto; }
.wrapper .hover-toggle .mdc-simple-menu          { width: 100%; top: 100% !important; position: absolute; right: 0 !important; left: 0 !important; z-index: 1; padding: 0; }

.mdc-simple-menu .mdc-list, 
.mdc-simple-menu .mdc-list-group                 { padding: 0; }

/* Hover Effects */
.hover-toggle .mdc-simple-menu--open             { opacity: 0; transform: scale(0, 0) translateY(-40px); transition: .2s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0.2, 1); position: absolute; transform-origin: left top 0px; left: 0px; top: 0px;  }
.hover-toggle:hover .mdc-simple-menu--open   { opacity: 1; transform: scale(1,1) translateY(0); }

.mdc-simple-menu .mdc-list-item:before       { opacity: 0;  position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; -webkit-transition: opacity .12s cubic-bezier(0,0,.2,1); transition: opacity .12s cubic-bezier(0,0,.2,1); border-radius: inherit; background: var(--mdc-theme-primary); content: ""; }
.mdc-simple-menu .mdc-list-item:hover:before  { opacity: .1; }
.mdc-simple-menu .mdc-list-item:active:before { opacity: .2; }
```